# How can I tell a chrome.app.window to open on a specific screen under Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a google [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). This application opens up a window via the [chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create) API.

The **problem** is that in a **multi-screen setup** I seemingly do not have any control over where my window is opened(main screen or secondary screen).

Is there still a way to **directly** (from within the application) or **indirectly**(e.g.: via Windows settings) influence the placement of my chrome-app window?

FYI: Under MacOS I can at least indirectly influence where the window is opened, since the window is always opened on the main-screen. And on MacOS you can set the main-screen in the OS-settings. But I have not found where I could do that in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to influence the window creation under Windows in an **indirect** manner. You can also [set which screen is the primary one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-set-primary-monitor-in-extended-desktop/e9aaef4e-1dc7-4139-9b4a-f5b562d4fd27).

Any **direct** ways of setting the screen of a chrome-app-window will trump my indirect solution, but that does not seem to be supported.